# g++ compiling error: std::ctype<char>, std::__detail, std::allocator<Taquart

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile a C++ program that uses an external library (cairo) on OS X 10.8.5. Previously, the same program was compiled on Linux successfully. Unfortunately I can't seem to get the program to compile, and getting the following error. Although I tried several things, I don't have a solution right now. I am using llvm-g++-4.2. Any help to explain what is going on and solve this issue is much appreciated. Thank you!

```
g++ -O3 -Wall moment_tensor.cpp -o focimt getopts.o faultsolution.o 
focimtaux.o inputdata.o timedist.o traveltime.o usmtcore.o 
trinity_library.o -L/opt/local/lib/ -lcairo    

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:    
"std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const", referenced from:    
              Options::showHelp(char*) in getopts.o
"std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)", 
referenced from:    
      TransferSolution(Taquart::SolutionType,std::list<Taquart::FaultSolution,
std::allocator<Taquart::FaultSolution> >&)in usmtcore.o    
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64   
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [focimt] Error 1}
```

Comment: Maybe the usmtcore.o and getopts.o libs aren't compiled correctly for x86_64? Not exactly your application but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607258/ios-static-library-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64

Comment: Thanks! but these are subroutines, and I doubt they are an issue.

Comment: `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64` looks like they're an issue

Comment: My guess so far is that showHelp and TransferSolution used in those subroutines are not in my g++ (version 4.2) standard library. Unfortunately I don't think OS X 10.8.5 that I have allows me to upgrade g++ any further.

Comment: It turned out that I made a mistake by not removing *.o files from a previous compile on a Linux machine. Once these were removed, I was able to compile the programme with a minor warning. Thanks for your time!

Comment: usmtcore.o and getopts.o are not "subroutines"; your terminology is off.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you copy/pasted binaries from another platform. Those binaries (probably the `.o` files) were compiled against a different standard library implementation. When attempting to link everything together on the new platform, the symbols don't match up with *this* platform's standard library implementation internals, so your linker complains.

You got lucky, actually: if the symbols had matched in name only, you could have had subtle runtime errors.

Never port binaries like this. Compile everything on the target system, or on an identical platform. Don't store binaries in version control.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that the *.o files were removed within the Makefile after every run through a make clean. It turns out that it was not the case. Otherwise I wouldn't have ported the files.